# linux get process name from pid within kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

hi 
i have used sys_getpid() from within kernel to get process id
how can I find out process name from kernel struct? does it exist in kernel??

thanks very much

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[struct task_struct](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1378) contains a member called [comm](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1545), it contains `executable name excluding path`.

Get [current macro from this file](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/tile/include/asm/current.h) will get you the name of the program that launched the current process (as in insmod / modprobe).

Using above info you can use get the name info.

Comment: comm is a buffer of TAK_COMM_LENGTH which is a 16-byte buffer. In case the executable name is greater than 16 bytes, is there still a way (apart from filp_open of procfs) to get the complete task name?

Comment: `current->comm` contains thread name. Which can be changed by pthread_setname_np or corresponding syscall.

Comment: the links on this answer are now dead

Comment: I can't edit the answer because the suggested edits queue is full, but I'd replace the dead lxr links with the ones from bootlin: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/include/linux/sched.h#L624

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but [find_task_by_pid_ns](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.38/kernel/pid.c#L417) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

My kernel module loads with "modprobe -v my_module --allow-unsupported -o some-data" and I extract the "some-data" parameter. The following code gave me the entire command line, and here is how I parsed out the parameter of interest:

```
struct mm_struct *mm;
unsigned char x, cmdlen;

mm = get_task_mm(current);
down_read(&mm->mmap_sem);

cmdlen = mm->arg_end - mm->arg_start;
for(x=0; x<cmdlen; x++) {
    if(*(unsigned char *)(mm->arg_start + x) == '-' && *(unsigned char *)(mm->arg_start + (x+1)) == 'o') {
        break;
    }
}
up_read(&mm->mmap_sem);

if(x == cmdlen) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "inject: ERROR - no target specified\n");
    return -EINVAL;
}

strcpy(target,(unsigned char *)(mm->arg_start + (x+3)));
```

"target" holds the string after the -o parameter. You can compress this somewhat - the caller (in this case, modprobe) will be the first string in mm->arg_start - to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at the special files in `/proc/<pid>/`

For example, `/proc/<pid>/exe` is a symlink pointing to the actual binary.

`/proc/<pid>/cmdline` is a null-delimited list of the command line, so the first word is the process name.

Comment: I believe Malesh N. wants to be able to do this from kernel code.

Comment: This _can_ be achieved from kernel space using `filp_open`, @craig65535